# pgfplots: suppress labels in groupplot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

In the following MWE, the Y-label overlaps with the left-hand-side plot, and therefore looks bad. I would like to suppress it (thus leaving the Y-label only for the LHS plot). How to achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    ylabel right/.style={
        after end axis/.append code={
            \node [rotate=90, anchor=north] at (rel axis cs:1,0.5) {#1};
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={group size=2 by 1},
        legend cell align=right,
        legend pos=north east,
        ylabel={Y label},
        xlabel={X label},
    ]
    \nextgroupplot
        \addplot+ [
                scatter/classes={
                a={mark=square,black},
                b={mark=square*,black},
                c={mark=10-pointed star,draw=black},
                d={mark=*,black},
                e={mark=oplus,draw=black},
                f={mark=otimes,draw=black},
                g={mark=+,black},
                h={mark=star,black}
            },
            scatter, only marks,
            scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        ]
        table [meta=label] {
             x   y    label
            2.7  3396 a
            6.2 1945 b
            27.3 28 c
            12.6 58 d
            0.58 789 e
            0.73 417 f
            0.73 985 g
            0.81 741 h
        };
        \legend{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}
        \draw[dashed,thick] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:0.9,990);
        \nextgroupplot[xmin=0.4,xmax=1,ymin=400,ymax=1000]
        \addplot+ [
            scatter/classes={
                e={mark=oplus,draw=black},
                f={mark=otimes,draw=black},
                g={mark=+,black},
                h={mark=star,black}
            },
            scatter, only marks,
            scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        ]
        table [meta=label] {
             x   y  label
            0.58 789 e 
            0.73 417 f 
            0.73 985 g 
            0.81 741 h 
        };
  \end{groupplot}
  \node (title) at ($(group c1r1.center)!0.5!(group c2r1.center)+(0,4cm)$) {Some title};
   \draw[thick,blue,->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt]
        (group c1r1.east) -- (group c2r1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add `ylabels at=edge left` to the `group style` option:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz automatically
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    ylabel right/.style={
        after end axis/.append code={
            \node [rotate=90, anchor=north] at (rel axis cs:1,0.5) {#1};
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={group size=2 by 1,ylabels at=edge left},% <- changed
        legend cell align=right,
        legend pos=north east,
        ylabel={Y label},
        xlabel={X label}
    ]
    \nextgroupplot
        \addplot+ [
                scatter/classes={
                a={mark=square,black},
                b={mark=square*,black},
                c={mark=10-pointed star,draw=black},
                d={mark=*,black},
                e={mark=oplus,draw=black},
                f={mark=otimes,draw=black},
                g={mark=+,black},
                h={mark=star,black}
            },
            scatter, only marks,
            scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        ]
        table [meta=label] {
             x   y    label
            2.7  3396 a
            6.2 1945 b
            27.3 28 c
            12.6 58 d
            0.58 789 e
            0.73 417 f
            0.73 985 g
            0.81 741 h
        };
        \legend{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}
        \draw[dashed,thick] (axis cs:0,0) rectangle (axis cs:0.9,990);
        \nextgroupplot[xmin=0.4,xmax=1,ymin=400,ymax=1000]
        \addplot+ [
            scatter/classes={
                e={mark=oplus,draw=black},
                f={mark=otimes,draw=black},
                g={mark=+,black},
                h={mark=star,black}
            },
            scatter, only marks,
            scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        ]
        table [meta=label] {
             x   y  label
            0.58 789 e 
            0.73 417 f 
            0.73 985 g 
            0.81 741 h 
        };
  \end{groupplot}
  \node (title) at ($(group c1r1.center)!0.5!(group c2r1.center)+(0,4cm)$) {Some title};
   \draw[thick,blue,->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt]
        (group c1r1.east) -- (group c2r1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]